# GWT handle back, refresh, close buttons

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, mvp4g

I'm trying to run some RPC calls when the user closes the window, refreshes it or clicks the back button *but* just for one single page. I found a post talking about handling but the solution is not working well, missing back button handler (not working) and always is for all page on the web, I can't find something for remove handler if you leave from page

```
    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
                    event.setMessage("You sure?");
                }
            });

    Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

                @Override
                public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {

                    // Execute code when window closes!
                System.out.println("ble ! ");

                }
            });
```

Framework: GWT 2.4 with mvp4g.
Browsers: FF and Chrome.

Comment: "Not work" is not a description of a problem. What's not working? Any errors? Code not being called? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Pressing back button is not showing the message dialog, thats not working, unlike close browser/tab, change url or refresh that fire the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Because i use mvp4g framework i found a solution there , you need to extends your presenter with CyclePresenter and override onLoad and onUnload methods. These methods fire when view is load/unload from DOM, i tested and work for all cases, f5, back button, close browser/tab, go other web and call others events. Now i cant put some code there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the handler when you leave the page and then re-add it when you enter the page again. You have the "add" side covered with the above code, you are missing the "remove" part. You do that by using the `HandlerRegistration` object that is returned from the `add*Handler` methods. When you want to remove the registered handler, you just call the `HandlerRegistration.removeHandler()` method:

```
HandlerRegistration windowClosingHandler = Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        // Handle window closing
    }
});
// From now on the CloseHandler will be fired

// ...
// Somewhere else:
windowClosingHandler.removeHandler();
// From now on the CloseHandler won't be fired
```

Comment: Igor, removeHandler its working but when user click back button the method onClose (CloseHandler) not execute and i cant remove handler.